# VB 2008 Express on W8.1: "this task requires the application to have elevated permissions"

Tags: .net

I'm trying to migrate from XP os to W8.1.
In W8.1 I when I try to run project from the IDE (VB 2008 Express) I got this 
message :
"this task requires the application to have elevated permissions"
UAC is disabled
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0crY.png
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soved this way :
I use Total commander/MultiCommander to open the project,and I configure the file manager shortcut to run as Administrator,then everything I open is "as Administrator",seems to work fine.